# What 'mythical creature' is David searching for?

Tags: ai-artificial-intelligence

What 'mythical creature' is David, the child mecha, searching for in the movie Artificial Intelligence?

Comment: Hi Faiza! Welcome to SFF Stackexchange, looks like the question already has an answer, which should hopefully be helpful. While you're here, please take the time to read the [tour], and look at other questions we have here to get a feel for the site. I very much look forward to seeing your next question!

Answer (score 4):

He is searching for the Blue Fairy (or the [Fairy with the Turquoise Hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_with_Turquoise_Hair)), the character from the Pinocchio story who first brought the puppet to life (in the Disney version of the story), and later turned it into a real boy (in both the original book by Collodi and the Disney version). David believes/hopes that the Blue Fairy can similarly turn him into a real boy too.

Comment: You might want to mention that this creature is fictional, not mythical

Comment: Isn't it both @Valorum ? The Oxford dictionary defines "mythical" as "occurring in or characteristic of myths or folk tales". Pinocchio surely counts as a folk tale, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Pinnochio isn't a folk tale

Comment: As far as I know, Pinocchio was created by Carlo Collodi in his novel The Adventures of Pinocchio,1881,  and thus is a fictional character. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Pinocchio

Comment: There is a nice discussion here https://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1047&context=the-mall  "Collodi’s version of Pinocchio contains some magical qualities but generally follows the genre of a folktale. [It] draws from traditional Italian stories and other adventurous tales, a common characteristic amongst folktales. “It relies heavily on the Tuscan novella or short-story tradition to which Boccaccio’s Decameron belongs, and also on classical sources, such as Homer and Dante..”

Comment: To be nitpicky, it was only the Blue Fairy from the Disney movie that brought Pinocchio to life. In the book Pinocchio came from a magic block of wood, that as far as we know had nothing to do with the Fairy with the Turquoise Hair.

Comment: I am wondering if myths are meant to be slightly less fictional than pure fiction. Implication that they were inspired by actual events or people. Pinocchio is definitely not mythical whereas characters such as Ulysses it is much more of a gray area. Anyway, the Blue Fairy is definitely fictional also.

Comment: That's true @BjornEriksson , I'll include that point.